# AppImage doesn't run when using "; exit" after the command

Tags: arch-linux, zsh, exit

I downloaded the AppImage of [Syncplay](https://syncplay.pl) and put it in `$HOME/Applications` and created an alias in `zsh` to run it from terminal and then exit. In `~/.zshrc` I have,

```bsh
$ grep syncplay ~/.zshrc
alias syncplay="setsid Applications/Syncplay/Syncplay-1.6.9-x86_64.AppImage"
```

And it works (and since I'm using `setsid`, I can close the terminal):

[image]

Now I want to automatically close the terminal after it's opened, so I changed the alias to

```bsh
$ grep syncplay ~/.zshrc
alias syncplay="setsid Applications/Syncplay/Syncplay-1.6.9-x86_64.AppImage; exit"
```

But it won't open anymore. The command runs and the terminal is closed, but the program isn't opened. What's happening? I did the same thing for Telegram and it worked.

Linux distribution: Arch Linux

Window Manager: BSPWM

Comment: What operating system are you using? Please [edit] your question and add this information since it is usually very relevant.

Comment: Also, try changing the alias to `setsid Applications/Syncplay/Syncplay-1.6.9-x86_64.AppImage & exit` or adding a small delay:  `alias syncplay="setsid Applications/Syncplay/Syncplay-1.6.9-x86_64.AppImage; sleep 3; exit"`. Does that make any difference?

Comment: @terdon Adding  `; sleep 3; exit` fixes it completely.

Comment: Yay! I posted it as an answer then.

Comment: @terdon Thank you! <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the `exit` command is killing the shell too soon. Try adding a small delay to your alias:

```bsh
alias syncplay="setsid Applications/Syncplay/Syncplay-1.6.9-x86_64.AppImage; sleep 3; exit".
```

That should help.

Comment: See also `cmd &|` or `cmd &!` to start a disowned job (though still attached to the tty, it's not equivalent to using setsid)